# How to remove error while using variable "la" in scatter chart?

Tags: java, android, gps, double, scatter-plot

**Obtaining GPS coordinates:**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
    location.getAltitude();
    location.getAccuracy();
    double la,lo,al,aq;
    location.setLatitude(la= location.getLatitude());
    location.setLatitude(lo=location.getLongitude());
    location.setLatitude(al=location.getAltitude());
    location.setLatitude(aq = location.getAccuracy());
    textView.append("\n"+la);
```

**Plotting "la" value in scatter chart:**

```
    ScatterChart scatterChart =(ScatterChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    List<ChartData> values = new ArrayList<>();
    float longi = (float) la;


    values.add(new ChartData(4f, 6f));
    values.add(new ChartData(10f, 10f));


    scatterChart.setData(values);
    scatterChart.setGesture(true);
    scatterChart.setDescription("Location");
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: "float longi=(float) la;" In here, variable "la" can not use.I want to use la(latitude) value to plot in scatter chart.

Answer (score 0):

try `float longi=la.floatValue();` intead of `float longi = (float) la;`.
so the code should be

```
ScatterChart scatterChart =(ScatterChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
List<ChartData> values = new ArrayList<>();
float longi = la.floatValue();


values.add(new ChartData(4f, 6f));
values.add(new ChartData(10f, 10f));


scatterChart.setData(values);
scatterChart.setGesture(true);
scatterChart.setDescription("Location");
```